# Tap gestures don't recognise offset change on a View in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a "button" that I need to offset to a different position using the `.offset(y: someVal)`.

I have the layout of the View as I like it but the hit area seems to be at the area before the offset was applied.

This is my code:

```
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            ZStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                Image(systemName: "someIcon")
                    .foregroundColor(myColor)
            }
            .frame(width: centerBtnRadius * 2, height: centerBtnRadius * 2)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: centerBtnRadius)
                    .stroke(myColor, lineWidth: 1)
            )
            .onTapGesture {
                //...
            }
            .onLongPressGesture(perform: {
                //...
            })
            .offset(y: centerBtnOffsetY)
            
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Text(labelText)
                    .scaledToFit()
            }

        }
        .frame(width: Constants.tbItemWidth, height: Constants.tbItemHeight)
    }
```

Now I've tried placing the modifier before others on the nested `ZStack` without success. It also must be after the `.overlay` modifier that positions my border around the `Circle()`. (I'm also open for ideas to make border different if it needs to be a part of the solution!)

My question is:

How can I make sure that my press gestures are catched by the whole Circle element after I've re-positioned it with the `.offset` modifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the offset modifier from after the tap gestures modifiers to before. By doing this, the tap gestures modifiers will take the offset into account for the "tap area".

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        ZStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.white)
            Image(systemName: "someIcon")
                .foregroundColor(myColor)
        }
        .frame(width: centerBtnRadius * 2, height: centerBtnRadius * 2)
        .overlay(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: centerBtnRadius)
                .stroke(myColor, lineWidth: 1)
        )
        .offset(y: centerBtnOffsetY) // Changed line
        .onTapGesture {
            //...
        }
        .onLongPressGesture(perform: {
            //...
        })
        
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            Text(labelText)
                .scaledToFit()
        }

    }
    .frame(width: Constants.tbItemWidth, height: Constants.tbItemHeight)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't do the trick unfortunately and it's something I tried beforehand. The tab area is working normally without the offset modifier but once I set it, the tab area remains in the same place...

Comment: @Rick what do you mean by tab? Also what do you want to be clickable? The circle, right? When I originally tested your code, the tap area was not in the correct area as you said. When I tested after moving the modifier, it worked for me.

Comment: Yes I meant the tap area. And you are correct. When using preview, The tab area actually works as expected but on real device or simulator, it does not. I'm wrapping this View in a UIHostingController where I'm setting some constraints. I'm essentially overlaying this SwiftUI view as a subView on window in this case. Maybe that's affecting my situation...

Comment: So that was indeed the case. I was setting a heightAnchor on the UIViewControler that wrapped around the view. So the problem is fixed and your input indeed helped out! So I'll give you a correct answer for the help 